# php version greater than 5.0 and register globals?

Tags: php, variables, global

we are changing servers and just installed php 5.3. the new server gave this error:
Undefined variable: HTTP_SERVER_VARS
we noticed register globals is turned off.
on php.net website, there is a reason it was turned off for php > 4.2;
question is, what do i do so that i don't get the Undefined variable: HTTP_SERVER_VARS, especially when i can't turned on register globals?

thanks.

Comment: The situation is similar, but `register_globals` doesn't have anything to do with `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS`. The existence of the `$HTTP_*_VARS` arrays are controlled by the `register_long_arrays` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `$_SERVER`, `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE`. They aren't affected by `register_globals`.

For more details, see the [superglobals manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php).

Answer (score 3):

if you don't want to change `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` to `$_SERVER` in all php files, you can use

```
global $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;
$HTTP_SERVER_VARS = $_SERVER;
```

Comment: Saved me a lot of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Up until PHP 5.3 there is a php.ini setting for that:

```
register_long_arrays = On
```

It'll show up a deprecation note however.

There's likewise an option for `register_globals`

And there's a whole chapter dedicated on the why. Might be a good opportunity to read it:
http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php